# nginx-ingress shows HTTP Error 404 for a react app deployed on Domain path, but works for subdomain path

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Here is my ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: 8link-app-kubernetes-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: link8.in
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: link8-app-prod-svc
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
  - host: test.link8.in
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: link8-app-prod-svc
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
```

In the above ingress, I have the same Front-end service which is defined to be run on both Domain and sub-domain (for the testing), it is working for sub-domain but not for the domain.

I get Error 404 on domain path:
[image]

Following is my DNS settings, where value is my Ingress Address:
[image]

***UPDATE:***

[image]

Comment: May I ask you which ingress are you using and how have you deployed it?

Comment: @JakubSiemaszko I'm using Nginx-ingress on digital ocean managed k8s cluster

Comment: Could you post the output of kubectl describe ing 8link-app-kubernetes-ingress? Also, how about deleting the subdomain, trying to make it work on the domain and than adding the subdomain?

Comment: @JakubSiemaszko added the command result in UPDATE section of question

Comment: @JakubSiemaszko I also tried removing test.8link.in entry, no luck still

Comment: Could you check the DNS and remove A record for test and see if anything changes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237404/discussion-between-kushal-and-jakub-siemaszko).

Comment: Share a `curl -v link8.in` output.

Comment: @S.D. Its giving me my application webpage in curl output, but in browser, I get nginx 404 error, don't understand why?

Comment: Aah I see, it is working in another browser too just not in chrome

Comment: @Kushal so does it work for you now?

Comment: @JakubSiemaszko it was working all along,  or just in chrome browser somehow

Comment: @Kushal sometimes chrome "caching" dns resolves. You need to close chrome and reopen. Maybe a bunch of deep refresh too.

Comment: @OrbánZoltán: yes I had to remove all the data related to my site domain from chrome, now it works fine

Comment: @Kushal could you post your findings as an answer?

Comment: @JakubSiemaszko my problem wasn't related to k8s; it was working from start. Just I had to clear everything for my domain in chrome storage

Answer (score 1):

In order to clear things for anyone, who will try to figure out the answer.

The question was answered by the author.

The problem was not in `Kubernetes` resources of any kind, it was a browser-specific issue, clearing the browser storage solved the problem.

> my problem wasn't related to k8s;
> it was working from start.
> Just I had to clear everything for my domain in chrome storage

---

[image]